How to achieve translated string in metadata in a simpler way in server-side components in Next.js
My ultimate goals to achieve translated metadata in Next.js server-side components.
Here's a valid code of mine in a app/[lang]/admin/page.tsx:
import { Metadata } from "next";
    
interface IProps {
  params: {
    lang: string;
  };
}

import { serverLang } from "@/app/[lang]/dictionaries.js";

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { lang },
}: IProps): Promise<Metadata> {
  const t = await serverLang(lang);

  return {
    title: t("Dashboard"),
  };
}

export default async function Dashboard({ params: { lang } }: IProps) {
  const t = await serverLang(lang);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{t("Dashboard")}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

I want to simplify the metadata declaration in every component simply like below:
export const metadata = {
  title: t("Next.js"), //  t() is not available
  description: t("Generated by Next.js"),
};

export default async function Dashboard({ params: { lang } }: IProps) {
  const t = await serverLang(lang);
  // ...rest of the code here
};

or something as simple as:
import { setMetadata } from "@/utils/metadata";
setMetadata("Next.js", "Generated by Next.js"); // translation will be done inside the function

// Dashboard() component code here

What I tried so far
I've made a custom file with all the relavant code like:
import { Metadata } from "next";

interface IProps {
  params: {
    lang: string;
  };
}

import { serverLang } from "@/app/[lang]/dictionaries.js";

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { lang },
}: IProps): Promise<Metadata> {
  const t = await serverLang(lang);

  return {
    title: t("Dashboard"),
  };
}

export function setMetadata = (title, description) => {
    //  I got stuck here
}

